# How do I establish how many chickens fit on my rotisserie?

Tags: chicken, skewers, rotisserie

I have a large rotisserie BBQ with double skewers side by each. I would like to get an idea of how many whole chickens I can roast at the same time. The skewers can fit about 5 small chickens (3-4 lbs) each, but I'm wondering if skewers will fit side by side and still rotate without rubbing.

What is the Average widest diameter of a small chicken?

I hoping that someone here with access to a bunch of small chickens can measure a few at the widest part and provide their results.

Comment: You could nip down to your local supermarket with a tape measure… just ignore the stares ;)

Comment: This really depends on location, chicken sizes vary around the world.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the size varies greatly.  However, once ready to put on the rotisserie, you could also truss or tie the birds, compacting them a bit and helping to create clearance. Seems to me that you could get a rough idea with two chickens, by placing one on each rotisserie.

Comment: The nice thing about that test is that you can avoid waste if they clash, just by sliding one asking until they don't. But I suspect you'd end up with 5 chickens on one and 4 on the other if you can line them up perfectly, or 4 and 3 so the widest parts fit in between each other